# Finding a general expression for $\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k} \exp\left(\frac{ick}{n}\right)$?

Tags: summation

Consider the sum
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k} \exp\left(\frac{ick}{n}\right).
$$

I have heard of methods that treat exponential sums. I was wondering if it's possible to find general expressions for exponential sums with "weights". Note that $a_{k}$ in general is a decreasing function of $k$.

Note that c is any constant and assume that $n\to\infty$ .

Comment: Thanks for the edits Mr.Brian.

Answer (score 0):

Your $a_k$ are strictly related with the [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series), expressed in the complex form.

Since you put $n$ at the denominator of the argument of $\exp $, when $n \to \infty$ you are moving towards a Rieman sum and thus towards the Fourier integral transform, if you can "extract" the $1 / n$ coefficient from the $a_k$'s, while maintaining the required convergence criteria for the Fourier series/transform.